# Answered, edited time format

Tags: feature-request

I don't know if this has to do with one's country of origin. But I find the time stamps, the ones that say `answered Apr 5 '11 at 7:01` or `edited Nov 25 '12 at 23:07` very unreadable.

If it was me I would have chosen `answered Apr 5 2011 at 7:01` or simply `answered 4/5/2011 7:01`

At the very least this should be configurable per user, in the settings or something.

Comment: :) wow, many people like their dates formated the way they are. How tolerant of them.

Comment: There is no requirement to comment on votes, besides, if we did then comments would be full of generic crap and no longer useful "I do not agree" "I do not want this feature, kthks".

Comment: only, there is a difference between "I don't need this" and "I think this is a bad idea" which you can't differentiate just based on vote.

Comment: I find current format is *unambiguous* (readable or not, not relevant to me), and I humbly dislike the second format of your proposal: unless one of the number is larger than 12, I won't be able to say which is which on the first time. OTOH, I was a bit surprised why you didn't propose ISO 8601 format in the first place.

Comment: Well, I don't need this and I would rather see SO devs work on features that I actually find useful. That's my personal opinion which I am free to express with a vote if I choose to. Seeing as you're already at -13  I don't see any reason to downvote though.

Comment: If this feature (hopefully) will be implemented in future, I vote for support of [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) presentation format (YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: At least make this customisable on a per-user basis, so that each can choose his own way to display dates and not bother anyone else with it.

Answer (score 5):

> very unreadable

They use a textual month in either case, which simply leaves day and year.
Is that so hard?

I don't see how a change to full year is much more readable, to be honest. Certainly not to the extreme to introduce an entirely new "per user" system, which we don't really have at the moment.

Comment: Again, it may be because I grow up reading and writing dates in a different way, but specially that `'` character before the year, makes it very hard to read for me.

Comment: @Ali Most of the world outside of the United States (which is to say, the majority of the SE audience) uses D/M/Y rather than M/D/Y.

Comment: YYYY/MM/DD is the ISO standard and the only format that cannot be confused.

Comment: In [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), the separator is a dash rather than slash; so the format is YYYY-MM-DD.